# Reflection: Type of item contained in non-generic subclass of generic list

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class MyList : List<MyClass>
```

How can I get the type `MyClass` through reflection if I have an `object` that contains an instance of `MyList`? The list can be empty, so I can't do something like `myList[0].GetType()`.

p.s. I can't just stop using `MyList` and directly use the generic List instead (the situation is a bit more complicated, and there are reasons for "hiding" the generic argument), so I can't pick up `MyClass` through `GetGenericArguments()`.

Comment: can you modify the class `MyList` to insert a static `GetGenericType` method returning `typeof(MyClass)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var elementType = (
    from iface in myList.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    where iface.IsGenericType
    where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)
    select iface.GetGenericArguments()[0])
        .Single();
```

I use `IList<T>` instead of list. This is more generic. However, there is also the change of a type implementing multiple `ILis<T>` versions (such as `IList<string>` and `IList<int>`).

Comment: I just inserted this into the code and it works for the "directly inherits from List" scenario (and possibly for any scenario, I'll have to check). Trying to wrap my head around it as I type :D

Comment: So if I'm understanding this code correctly, it works because since List<T> implements IList<T>, any subclass also implements IList<T>, and no matter how many layers of inheritance separates them, it will still be in the list of interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the base type, which will be `List<MyClass>`; from it you can get the generic type argument with [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

Comment: The problem is, I may have different kinds of lists with different inheritance trees, and the function needs to work on all of them as long as they implement IList. I may be able to make this work by using the base type but I'd prefer an "get the type of item the collection contains" approach if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyList list = new MyList();
Type baseTypeGenericArgument = list.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
string argumentTypeName = baseTypeGenericArgument.GetType().FullName;
```

Comment: Using `BaseType` is a bit tricky, since `List<T>` can be the base of the base.

Comment: @Steven : but here is we have strong requirement that we need base class fo the MyList

Comment: The question also states `List<MyClass>` as the base class, so we can simply give `argumentTypeName  = typeof(MyClass);` as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is your class implements generic interfaces? you can use the following code:

```
Type argument = GetGenericArgument(typeof(MyList), typeof(IList<>));
//...
static Type GetGenericArgument(Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition) {
    Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
    for(int i = 0; i < interfaces.Length; i++) {
        if(!interfaces[i].IsGenericType) continue;
        if(interfaces[i].GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition)
            return interfaces[i].GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Without interfaces you can try the following:

```
class A { }
class B { }
class G<T> { }
class G1<T> : G<A> { }
class G2 : G1<B> { }
//...
Type argument1 = GetGenericArgument(typeof(G2)); // B
Type argument2 = GetGenericArgument(typeof(G2),1 ); // A
//...
static Type GetGenericArgument(Type type, int level = 0) {
    do {
        if(type.IsGenericType && 0 == level--)
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    while(type != null);
    return null;
}
```